# Remove Items from Arrays inside an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to remove specific items from Arrays inside an Array and also to remove arrays inside the same array, using `.map` and `.filter`.

---

Here's an example of the array:

```
items: [
    {
        title: 'dashboard',
        isValidateAccess: false,
    },
    {
        title: 'reports',
        isValidateAccess: true,
        children: [
            {
                title: 'attendancesReportMenu',
                isValidateAccess: true,
            },
            {
                title: 'holidaysReportMenu',
            },
            {
                title: 'absencesReportMenu',
                isValidateAccess: true,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        title: 'myDepartments',
        children: [
            {
                title: 'inconsistencies',
                isValidateAccess: true,
            },
            {
                title: 'absences',
            },
            {
                title: 'clocks',
                isValidateAccess: true,
            },
            {
                title: 'employees',
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

---

Basically, I want to remove all the items/arrays with `isValidateAccess` as `true`. This would be the result:

```
items: [
    {
        title: 'dashboard',
        isValidateAccess: false,
    },
    {
        title: 'myDepartments',
        children: [
            {
                title: 'absences',
            },
            {
                title: 'employees',
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

Comment: Why is the `reports` object removed in your result?

Comment: Please post your try first.

Comment: Because it has the ```isValidateAccess: true```. That's the tricky part, i don't want to remove only the items but also the array, case they have that as true.

Comment: I thought you only wanted to remove from the inner arrays, not the outer array.

Comment: My bad.. is this possible? :|

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to be specific about the code you've tried, what you expect, and what isn't working, and be as specific as possible about your criteria. Don't introduce new criteria like `isValidateAccess` in comments - edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's quite modern implementation

```js
const items = [
    {
        title: 'dashboard',
        isValidateAccess: false,
    },
    {
        title: 'reports',
        isValidateAccess: true,
        children: [
            {
                title: 'attendancesReportMenu',
                isValidateAccess: true,
            },
            {
                title: 'holidaysReportMenu',
            },
            {
                title: 'absencesReportMenu',
                isValidateAccess: true,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        title: 'myDepartments',
        children: [
            {
                title: 'inconsistencies',
                isValidateAccess: true,
            },
            {
                title: 'absences',
            },
            {
                title: 'clocks',
                isValidateAccess: true,
            },
            {
                title: 'employees',
            },
        ],
    },
]
const filter = (filterable) =>
  filterable
  .filter(item => !item.isValidateAccess)
  .map(item => ({
    ...item,
    children: item.children?.filter(i => !i.isValidateAccess)
  }))


  
console.log(filter(items))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `filter()` on the main array to remove the top-level elements, then use `forEach()` in the remaining elements so you can filter the `children` arrays.

```js
let items = [{
    title: 'dashboard',
    isValidateAccess: false,
  },
  {
    title: 'reports',
    isValidateAccess: true,
    children: [{
        title: 'attendancesReportMenu',
        isValidateAccess: true,
      },
      {
        title: 'holidaysReportMenu',
      },
      {
        title: 'absencesReportMenu',
        isValidateAccess: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'myDepartments',
    children: [{
        title: 'inconsistencies',
        isValidateAccess: true,
      },
      {
        title: 'absences',
      },
      {
        title: 'clocks',
        isValidateAccess: true,
      },
      {
        title: 'employees',
      },
    ],
  },
];

items = items.filter(item => !item.isValidateAccess);
items.forEach(item => item.children && (item.children = item.children.filter(child => !child.isValidateAccess)));

console.log(items);
```